# Contour plot for the quadratic approximation of the log-likelihood, based on the Taylor series

Tags: r, taylor-series, weibull

My aim is to make a contour plot for the quadratic approximation of the log-likelihood, based on the Taylor series, for a Weibull distribution.

But, as a beginner of R (and stats, too), I can't move forward to write a function to evaluate the log-likelihood give theta and data.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Here's the Hessian computation that I have, as a hint.

```
#observed information matrix
 jhat<-matrix(NA,nrow=2,ncol=2)
 jhat[1,1]<-n/gammahat^2+sum((y/betahat)^gammahat*
 (log(y/betahat))^2)
 jhat[1,2]<-jhat[2,1]<- n/betahat-sum(y^gammahat/betahat^(gammahat+1)*
 (gammahat*log(y/betahat)+1))
 jhat[2,2]<- -n*gammahat/betahat^2+gammahat*(gammahat+1)/
 betahat^(gammahat+2)*sum(y^gammahat)
 solve(jhat)
```

Additionaly, I have these estimates for gamma hat and beta hat, and those are the part I *think* I have to modify:

```
gammahat<-uniroot(function(x) n/x+sum(log(y))-n*
 sum(y^x*log(y))/sum(y^x),
 c(1e-5,15))$root

betahat<- mean(y^gammahat)^(1/gammahat)

weib.y.mle<-c(gammahat,betahat)
```

I have this function, but I think it doesn't use Taylor expansion:

```
log_lik_weibull <- function( data, param){ 
-sum(dweibull(data, shape = param[1], scale = param[2], log = TRUE)) }
```

Comment: I have this function, but I think it doesn't use Taylor expansion:

```R
 log_lik_weibull <- function( data, param){
  -sum(dweibull(data, shape = param[1], scale = param[2], log = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with any additional information you may have instead of posting it into the comment section.

Comment: Done. My apologies, first post here.